# AdControl in universal app show images too little

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a little problem with AdControl.
AdControl shows ads and my PubCenter counts everything, but images are too little like this (down):

[image]

```
    <ads:AdControl Grid.Row="2"
              AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
              ApplicationId="myid"
              AdUnitId="myunitid"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Height="80"
              IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="400"/>
```

Comment: Is the ad(s) the little button things at the bottom, or the blurred out text in your image? Not sure exactly what you're asking but at first glance it seems you could just throw it into `ViewBox` and apply your sizes to it instead and allow it to scale the ad's while retaining resolution.

Comment: Yes, this is ad. I want to this advertisement was larger size. Exactly, the same size as the white box.
My grid has 3 rows:
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

And in 3 row I want to place ads. I prepare this code according to this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-ads-walkthroughs-81-xaml-markup(v=msads.20).aspx
But my ad is very little.

Answer (score 1):

So you said you have your layout in a 3 row `Grid` like this;

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
      <RowDefinition Height="80"/> 
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
      <RowDefinition Height="80"/> 
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

...and you want your adverts to consume that "80" height of the 3rd row but still keep their resolution. So you could do something like this instead;

```
<ViewBox Grid.Row="2" Stretch="UniformToFill">
   <ads:AdControl Grid.Row="2"
                  AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                  ApplicationId="myid"
                  AdUnitId="myunitid"
                  IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"/>
</ViewBox>
```

This way it should take whatever the contents of the AdControl are and use them to fill the space you've provided (in this case, an "80" height you set in your Row Height, and whatever width of the device. With the `Stretch="UniformToFill"` set it should retain the resolution while filling that space and keep the same aspect ratio as whatever is provided to it.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I read a lot about this problem, I test many solution and I think this is problem with AdUnitID.My Ad in PubCenter has size 320x50, AdControl is a good size, because all row is white, only image is very little. I check test mode values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-test-mode-values(v=msads.10).aspx
and problem still have. Maybe when I develop my app in Windows Phone Store, problem solved? :) My page looks like: http://pastebin.com/wmuqXkZT Maybe someone test my ApplicationdID and AdUnitID?

Comment: If you set your height & width on the viewbox it should scale whatever is in it to that size just fine?

Comment: It seems that scales good and the problem is on the other side - with AdUnitID. I have any idea...